# Unclear instruction in Google Documents List API "Creating or uploading spreadsheets"

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I'm **trying to create a spreadsheet** via my android app. So far I've been only successful in creating an empty text document.  **Google's Spreadsheet API** instructs me to follow **Google Documents List API** in order to create a spreadsheet document in **Google Drive**. In **Google Documents List API** it says:

> To create a new, empty spreadsheet, follow the instructions in
> [**Creating a new document or file with metadata only**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_a_new_document_or_file_with_metadata_only). When doing so, use
> a category term of http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#spreadsheet.

In the link above I've found the next **.NET code**:

```
using System;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Documents;

namespace MyDocumentsListIntegration
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      DocumentsService service = new DocumentsService("MyDocumentsListIntegration-v1");

      // TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see Authorizing requests)

      // Instantiate a DocumentEntry object to be inserted.
      DocumentEntry entry = new DocumentEntry();

      // Set the document title
      entry.Title.Text = "Legal Contract";

      // Add the document category
      entry.Categories.Add(DocumentEntry.DOCUMENT_CATEGORY);

      // Make a request to the API and create the document.
      DocumentEntry newEntry = service.Insert(
          DocumentsListQuery.documentsBaseUri, entry);
    }
  }
}
```

I've used this code to try and create a spreadsheet, but only the third variant worked (using **`DocsService`**, without adding **`Category`** and using *`feedUrl`* URL object).

Here's part of my working code (`upload()` is being called when user clicks a button):

```
private void upload() {
        SpreadSheetAsyncTask sprdSheetAsyncTsk = new SpreadSheetAsyncTask();

        sprdSheetAsyncTsk.execute();

    }

    public class SpreadSheetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            spreadSheetService = new SpreadsheetService("Salary_Calculator");
            docService = new DocsService("Salary_Calculator");
            try {

                spreadSheetService.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                docService.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

                URL feedUrl = new URL(
                        "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/");
                URL tmpFeedUrl = new URL(
                        "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/key/private/full");

                DocumentEntry entry = new DocumentEntry();

                Calendar timeRightNow = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

                entry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(
                        "Salary Calculator Spreadsheet "
                                + timeRightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/"
                                + (timeRightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/"
                                + timeRightNow.get(Calendar.YEAR)));

//              Category object = new Category("spreadsheet",
//                      "http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#spreadsheet");
//              
//
//              entry.getCategories().add(object);
                
                /*
                 * TODO TEST AREA
                 */

                entry = docService.insert(feedUrl, entry);
                /*
                 * TODO TEST AREA
                 */
            } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
                cancel(true);
                loginDialog("Wrong username or password");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (ServiceException e) {
                cancel(true);
                loginDialog("Wrong username or password");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                loginDialog("Wrong username or password");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

The non working code uses the category object *`object`* (as shown in the code comment) above and uses `entry = spreadSheetService.insert(feedUrl, entry);`

**My question is - what did they want me to do when they wrote  `use a category term of http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#spreadsheet`?**

Comment: google-Spreadsheet-API demo: https://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn-history/r51/trunk/java/sample/spreadsheet/cell/CellDemo.java is good, and helped me lots, might point you in the right direction, but dont think it answers your question. Also check out DrEdit google drive example.

Comment: I don't see how they create the spreadsheet. My biggest issue is to create one from my application; editing one, as I've heard, is easy.